# JavaScript keeps returning 0

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   </head>
 <body>
     <form id="window">
       <input type="text" id="num1"><br />
         <input type="text" id="num2"><br />
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="main()"><br />
 </form>
    <script>
      var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
       function main(){
         alert(num1 + num2);
        }
    </script>
  </body>
   </html>
```

This is my code tell me what I am doing wrong because whenever I call the alert() it just returns 0 to the screen. I have tried it in different browsers but with no luck. Go easy on me because I have started only about a week ago!``

Answer (score 6):

It's because you're setting the values of `num1` and `num2` **once**, right at the beginning of the script when the  inputs don't have anything in them yet (`Number("")` is `0`), not each time `main` is called. Just move those two lines *into* `main` so the values of the inputs as of the button click are used:

```
function main(){
    var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
    var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
    alert(num1 + num2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `num1` and `num2` inside `main()`; Use below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   </head>
 <body>
     <form id="window">
       <input type="text" id="num1"><br />
         <input type="text" id="num2"><br />
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="main()"><br />
 </form>
    <script>
        function main(){
            var num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
            var num2 = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
            alert(num1 + num2);
        }
    </script>
  </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I want to ask the ones who have downvoted this answer, was the answer wrong or your mind?